# Cannot find vcvarsall.bat in virtualenv on Window 7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, distutils

My next command didn't work in virtualenv

```
pip install -U cryptography
```

I have this error `can't find vcvarsall.bat`

So I follow several helpfull post to

- Install **Visual Studio Express 2008 for C++**
- Add my path `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%`
- Check my registre key **ProductDir** at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VCExpress\9.0\Setup\VC** for my 32bit processor

But I always the same error ...

Please I need help, thanks

Comment: I don't understand why the update does not work, because the installation worked few months ago

Comment: I try too solutions, now I have  `... File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsall            raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']`

Comment: I solved the previous problem to install pywin32